# Richfaces 3.1.4 GA data scroller not working for IE11 but works on IE8

Tags: richfaces

My project using Richfaces  version 3.1.4 GA ..Our project plan to move on IE11 while testing we found Data scroller functionality **is not working on IE11** but **it works fine
 on IE8.**
Below is my code ..**which work fine on IE8 but not on IE11**

```
                  <f:facet name="header" >
                                    <rich:columnGroup id="search_results_col">
                                           <rich:column id="search_results_full_name" style="width:10px;">
                                           <h:outputText id="full_name_label" value="FULLNAME" style="width:200px;"/>
                                             <rich:spacer width="5px"/>
                                          </rich:column>    
                                        <rich:column id="search_results_col_nysid">
                                            <h:outputText id="booking_name_label" value="NYSID" style="width:200px;"/>
                                        </rich:column>                                                  
                                    </rich:columnGroup>
                          </f:facet>

                <rich:column  style="text-align:center;">
                        <h:outputText id="nm_txt" value="#{inmate.fullName}"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column  style="text-align:center;">
                        <h:outputText id="c_nysid_txt" value="#{inmate.nysid}"/>
               </rich:column>

     </rich:dataTable>   


        <rich:dataScroller align="left" for="search_results" maxPages="20" pagesVar="pageVar">

</rich:dataScroller>
```

Can you please  let me how I can make it run on IE 11 without changing Richfaces version..

Answer (score 2):

Try using a4j support code to trigger the action of datascroller.

```html
<rich:dataScroller align="left" for="search_results" maxPages="20" pagesVar="pageVar">
<a4j:support event="onpagechange"></a4j:support>
</rich:dataScroller>
```